# What do straight lines in the $p$-norm look like?

Tags: metric-spaces, geodesic

I know that:

- straight lines in the $2$-norm are just regular straight lines
- straight lines in the $1$-norm are lines made from horizontal and vertical segments
- straight lines in the $\infty$-norm are lines made from segments at multiples of $45$ degrees

But what do they look like for other values of $p$?

By "straight line", I mean a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to X$ such that $d(f(x), f(y)) = |x - y|$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the definition of a straight line?

Comment: @JulianMejia A subspace isometric to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You should put the definition of it in the body of your question. From my understanding, a straight line is a curve $r$ such that $\|r(t),r(s)\|_p=|t-s|$?Also, are you looking at straight lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or in general for a $\mathbb{R}^n$?.

Comment: Any 1-d subspace $U$ is isometric to $\mathbb R$ in any norm. Just take an unit vector $u\in U$ and the map $r(s) = su$. Then, $\|su - tu\| = |s-t|$. Have you missed something in your question?

Comment: @JulianMejia Just $\mathbb{R}^2$ is ok. I'm just trying to better understand intuitively what the $p$-norms look like. I know what circles look like, but not what straight lines look like.

Comment: @user251257 A line that makes a $90$ degree turn is straight in the $1$-norm, but not the $2$-norm, for example.

Comment: In particular, @user251257 shows other examples in addition to the examples in the question for $1$ and $\infty$ norm.  Can you show that some Euclidean line is **not** a "straight line" in your sense?

Comment: No, I don't mean linear subspace, I'm just talking about metric spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, you are asking, given two points $A$, $B$, what is the set of points $C$ satisfying the triangle equality $|AC|+|CB| = |AB|$. In an euclidean space, it is simply the segment $AB$.

In the case of 1-norm, it is an entire rectangle with corners in $A, B$ aligned with the axes, in the case of $\infty$-norm, it is a rectangle with corners in $A, B$ under the angle $45^\circ$.

However, note that the original (euclidean) segment $AB$ is still contained inside these rectangles. This is not a coincidence. By the very fact we are dealing with a vector space with a norm, ve have for every $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and a vector $v$ the following: $|\alpha v| + |(1-\alpha)v| = \alpha |v| + (1-\alpha)|v| = |v|$. So in any norm, the standard (euclidean) segment will always satisfy the triangle equality.

So your question is basically asking whether there is something extra to the standard segment in a general $p$-norm, as it is in the case of a 1-norm, or $\infty$-norm, and the answer is: No. Only the degeneracy of 1-norm and $\infty$-norm allows other points to satisfy the triangle equality.

Therefore, for any $p\in(1;\infty)$, the segments in the $p$-norm look the same as segments in 2-norm.